# Java System.out and String.format errors

Tags: java, printf, string-formatting

Hi I'm new at Java and I have two errors here is my code

```
class Klase {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        NewClass obj = new NewClass(7,31,1994); // new object
    }
}
```

My other class

```
 public class NewClass {
            private int month;
        private int day;
        private int year;

        public NewClass(int m, int d, int y){
            month = m;
            day = d;
            year = y;

            System.out.printf("Konstruktorius yra %s\n", this); // here are my first error
             }
```

/*The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not  applicable for the arguments (String, NewClass)*/

```
        public String toString(){
            return String.format("%d/%d/%d", month, day, year); // here are my second error
            }
        }
```

/*The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int)*/

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Both `String#format` and `PrintWriter#printf` have been around since Java 1.5.

Comment: Well I'm using jdk-8 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Your code works here. How did you set-up your project in Eclipse (or whatever IDE you're using)?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Kepler Service Release 2. Set up project File->New->Java Project

Comment: Does String.format("%d/%d/%d", new int[] { month, day, year }) work for you?

Comment: No it doesn't work...

Answer (score -2):

Your language level is lower than it should be. Go to Project > Properties > Java Compiler and set it to Java 8 (or whatever you want above Java 1.5). You may need to enable project specific settings.